# Javafx filechooser name filter

Tags: java, file, javafx, filechooser

i'd like to know if there's a way of filtering the names of files to make them selectable in the dialog to select files, for instance all files that starts for "A" and are in txt format, i searched a bit and i found only tips topics about the extension with the Extension filter, that's fine but i'd like to select just some file in a format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course , you can get some idea from this example; in Java Swing( I'm not sure how in JavaFX) you can filter files by name or extension like :

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("MP3 File","mp3");
fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter)`
```

Answer (score 5):

In JavaFX you can filter for particular file types by adding [`ExtensionFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.ExtensionFilter.html)s to the list of filters returned by `getExtensionFilters`, like so:

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.txt"));
```

The JavaFX file chooser does not support filtering by file name, only by extension. This is because most platforms don't support this functionality natively in their file choosers.

Comment: The question asks for JavaFX specifically, so this should be the proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
        chooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new ExtensionFilter("Excel Files", "*.xls"));
```

you can use add or addAll depending upon how many filters you want to add.